# Ceph gateway for Azure blob support

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, redhat, ceph, cephfs

Does ceph gateway support Azure blob storage?

In below link docs, they mentioned only S3 and Swift API supported. Can we use for azure blob?

https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/index.html

Or any open source object storage gateways are available and that has support to Azure blob. I know minio but we need to explore other products.

Answer (score 0):

As per official document by docs.ceph, Ceph object storge Supports two interfaces. First one is S3-Compatible and second one is Swift Compatible.

but other Best alternative apps just like Cepha are these following ([MinIO](https://min.io/), [Seaweedfs](https://seaweedfs.github.io/), [StorPool](https://storpool.com/), [GluserFs](https://www.gluster.org/), [DRBD](https://linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/))

More alternative visit this [Web Site](https://www.g2.com/products/red-hat-ceph-storage/competitors/alternatives)